# How to restore a linux root filesystem during operation?

Tags: linux, system-restore

I have a rough idea but not sure it's feasible. It's, in a machine with linux I have a hidden backup default filesystem as time goes, the machine becomes messy and it needs to reset to the factory system. Is it possible to overlay the root filesystem with the default filesystem while the machine running?

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea. I'd use a separate recovery partition instead.

Comment: Better solution.  Use a filesystem that supports snapshots (zfs/btrfs)  Take a snapshot, or even better setup automatic snapshots so you can roll back.  Possibly augment that with something like etckeeper, and other tools that let you track changes easily over time.

Comment: @Zoredache I agree with you. That's definitely one of solutions. Thank you,

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, It does sound horrible. But I just want to make sure if it is feasible.